# dvd menu with single text field that can change

Tags: video

I've been making a DVD menu with DVDstyler, and I'm fairly happy with how it looks. However, since space is limited and I have 5 scenes on one page, I want to have a single text box at the bottom that contains the name of the scene that is currently in focus. This doesn't seem possible with DVDstyler. Or is it?

If not, which other DVD authoring software should I acquire in order to have this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please break this up in to two questions.  The first part and the second part are distinct questions and someone that knows the answer to one may not know the answer to the other.

Comment: fair point, done :)